# Having trouble with an Excel formula in the data validation window

Tags: excel, validation

I'm trying to create a drop down list in Excel that updates automatically as more data is added to the source data column.  I do this by looking for the last cell that isn't blank with the following formula.

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(A:A,MATCH(LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""),A:A),A:A,0)))
```

Using this formula in a cell of the spreadsheet itself works perfect, but when I try to use it to create a list in the Data Validation menu I get the following:

[image]

[image]

Any ideas of where how to get this to work?

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you!

Edit:

As BigBen suggested, I tried removing CELL("address",       ) from my formula leaving just index and what's inside, but I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: Get rid of the `CELL` and just use the `INDEX`, I believe.

Comment: Cell gets me the address of that final cell with a value.  index would just get me the value itself which I can't use when inputting an address range.

Comment: Actually, you can do `$A$1:INDEX(....)`

Comment: Editted OP with results of that

Comment: `=OFFSET(A1,0,0,MATCH(LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""),A:A),A:A,0))`.

Comment: Thanks, Ben.  That did the trick.

Comment: @BigBen Is there a way to expand upon this function so that the validation list excludes a blank value that's in the source data inbetween the populated cells?

Comment: Possibly with a helper column. Also, what version of Excel are you working in?

Comment: I have Version 2205

Comment: Sorry - meaning Excel 365, Excel 2019, Excel 2017, i.e. does it support `FILTER` and other Dynamic Array formulas?

Comment: I have Excel 365, supports filter.